# SpeechRecognizer: isRecognitionAvailable() vs isOnDeviceRecognitionAvailable()

Tags: android

isRecognitionAvailable() -
Added in API level 8

> Checks whether a speech recognition service is available on the system. If this method returns false, SpeechRecognizer#createSpeechRecognizer(Context) will fail.

isOnDeviceRecognitionAvailable() -
Added in API level 31

> Checks whether an on-device speech recognition service is available on the system. If this method returns false, SpeechRecognizer#createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer(Context) will fail.

I want to build Speech to text feature in one of my apps. I'm unable to understand the difference between isRecognitionAvailable() and isOnDeviceRecognitionAvailable(). I need help with checking whether Speech recognition is available on the phone or not. Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech recognition can happen locally (on the phone) or remotely (on some server somewhere on the internet).  isOnDeviceRecognitionAvailable returns true if there is a speech recognizer that doesn't need the internet available.  isRecognitionAvailable will return true if any speech recognizer, local or remote, exists.

Why would you not want to use a remote solution?  It's likely slower, and there are privacy issues (their recorded speech would be sent to the cloud).  So there's applications where it isn't appropriate to use.  Thus why the two functions exist-  so you can make that choice.

Comment: Interesting takeaway on SpeechRecognizer in terms of security, whether or not to use on-device speech recognizer. Since API 31, it has required the RECORD AUDIO permission to be used.